# Can't get it to show "Invalid Score. Please Re-enter" for scores above 100

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement, for-loop, program-entry-point

noob here...

Been trying to write c programming for a group assignment. Got everything working smoothly except when it calculates scores above 100 ( for example 101). My question ask for categorizing scores and giving average, and finally, if it's outside the ranges, should give output informing the score is invalid and they need to re-enter. Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
int n=0,i=0;
int scores[100],average=0, total=0;
int outstanding=0,satisfactory=0,unsatisfactory=0;

printf("Number of scores you want to enter:\n");
scanf("%d",&n);//how many times the score needed to be entered

printf("Please enter the scores:\n");

for(i=0;i<n;i++)//store user input in array
{

scanf("%d", &scores[i]);

if ((scores[i]<0) && (scores[i]>100))
{
printf("\nScores invalid. Please re-enter:\n");
i--;
}
}

for(i=0;i<n;i++)// to categorize
{

if((scores[i]>=0) && (scores[i]<=59))
{
unsatisfactory++;

}
else if((scores[i]>=60) && (scores[i]<=89))
{
satisfactory++;

}
else if((scores[i]>=90) && (scores[i]<=100))
{
outstanding++;

}
}
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
{

total = total + scores[i];
average = total / n;
}

//print out results

printf("\n The number of unsatisfactory scores is : %d\n ", unsatisfactory);
printf("\n The number of satisfactory scores is : %d\n", satisfactory);
printf("\n The number of outstanding scores is : %d\n", outstanding);
printf("\n The average of the score is :    %d\n ", average);


return 0;
}
```

I suspected the problem would be at:

```
if ((scores[i]<0) && (scores[i]>100))
{
printf("\nScores invalid. Please re-enter:\n");
i--;
}
```

But not sure how to correct it. Even if I put `return main();`, it still don't give out the intended output ('Scores invalid. Please Re-enter.`) and return, instead continued with categorizing and averaging.

Help?With cherry on top?

Comment: Hint: next time, don't use complex boolean expressions for control.  Use simple expressions to load the bool results into temp local bools, then use the temps in the final conditional.  That way, you will be better able to inspect the temp values in your debug build and should then clearly see any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use || instead of && in your if statement.

`if ((scores[i]<0) || (scores[i]>100))`